# How to set the height of the main view which will be sum of the height of other Views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing a scale where I have 100 boxes and their vertical space. Here is the code for that. The below code indicates one Block. Ther will be 100 blocks. in that scale. The height of this block from Imageview and view is 6.7dp. 6.7*100= 670dp.

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/img_2"
   android:layout_width="6dp"
   android:layout_height="6.5dp"
   android:background="@color/boxcolor" />

                 
                   
<View
  android:layout_width="6dp"
  android:layout_height="0.2dp"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

> But when I set the height of a graph-view 670 dp it does not match the height of the scale.

```
        <charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="670dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11.7dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

> Here are the pictures that explain what it looks like.

[first_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLLCD.png),[image: picture]

> I cannot directly the height of the scale because the boxes are in the inner views.    so can't directly set the height that way.
> **Please check both pictures.**
>
> **Here is the whole code file**
> [XML file link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JDJ4bIDt1WegSunZ19rsD2xS7lraHgV8/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107708316268411928028&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[image]

Comment: Is `charts.LineChart` your custom view?

Comment: yes. this is the custom View.

Comment: You should try `Show layout boundaries` setting inside the developer options to check where your `line-chart` view really ends.

Comment: Please check the pictures. The line I have drawn is where the chart ends.  The line should equal to yellow point.

Comment: You should share the whole XML of the layout

Comment: that will be too much. 100 views etc. It will cover the whole page.

Comment: then omit the 100 views layout and just share their parents and chart view XML.

Comment: yeah i have added the file

Answer (score 0):

You can't count on math being consistent like that over dozens of objects of different size-  eventually rounding will kill you.  Devices aren't always exactly able to fill 1 dp, there might not be an even number of pixels in that size.  For example, 330 dpi is a common screen size, that would have 2.0625 pixels per dp.  That would likely round down to 2 for small numbers.  Add a few of those together and now you're off by a few pixels of cumulative error.  Where as the 600dp would still only be off by .0625 pixels, because it would calculate off the total.

If you want a view to go around other views, there's 2 ways to do it.  One is to make it the parent.  If so, put the other views inside it and make this view's height wrap_content.  The other is to use a ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout, make the height wrap_content, but constrain the top and bottom edges to the top of the first image and bottom of the last.

Comment: I have added the code file. could you please look at it.